# Validity in Spring Security SecUser SecRole

Tags: grails, spring-security

I need to provide roles to users on a subscription basis. So I created a domain like the following:

```
class UserRoleValidity {

    SecUser user
    SecRole role
    Date validFrom
    Date validTo

    static constraints = {
        validFrom nullable: true, blank: false
        validTo nullable: true, blank: false, validator: dateValidator
    }

    static def dateValidator = { val, obj ->
        if(!val || (val && !obj.validFrom)) {
            return true
        }
        val.equals(obj.validFrom) || val.after(obj.validFrom)
    }
}
```

The role will be valid for the user only if the current date is within the `validFrom` and `validTo` range. Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already configured spring security,then you don't need to create the  separate class to check user role and time between validation Just use the '@Secured' annotation for your controller action
as follows.
e.g

```
// provide the roles which you want to validate
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_COORDINATOR'])
def validateTimeToPerformAction(){

   /*
    If the current time is between given range return true
    Else return false
   */
}
```

Comment: But I'll still need to save validFrom and validTo dates and map them with the correct user and role. Where do you recommend I save these? Also I have over a hundred actions in multiple controllers. How to handle checking the time in every action?

Comment: Ok, then go with the what you are trying but, think for an optimization. Is your date range is predefined / fix for every allowed role?, if this is the case then better way is design one static Map OR dump a Map as a JSON string inside the user table against every user which will provide the date range and other constraints if required.